# In google-chrome on linux canvas drawImage in chrome v116 is 20x slower than in v114

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

After updating chrome to version 116 drawImage of the HTML canvas is suddenly 20x slower:

```
Chrome/114.0.0.0 - created 300 canvases in 30ms, drawImage in 39ms
Chrome/116.0.0.0 - created 300 canvases in 15ms, drawImage in 817ms
```

This makes drawing images 20x slower. I am on Ubuntu 22.04 64bit
If you want to test older version of chrome you can download it from https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1135561%2Fchrome-linux.zip?generation=1682460989187924&alt=media

This happened between 114 and 116, I can't find 115 to further narrow it down.

Here is minimal test code:

```js
// Create 300 canvases 25x25 to show creating canvases did not slow down
var t1 = Date.now(),
  i, can = [],
  o, img, log = '';
for (i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  o = {};
  o.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  o.context = o.canvas.getContext('2d');
  o.canvas.width = 25;
  o.canvas.height = 25;
  can.push(o);
}
log += 'created 300 canvases in ' + (Date.now() - t1) + 'ms, ';
// create one 1000x1000 canvas to be used as source image
t1 = Date.now();
img = {};
img.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
img.context = img.canvas.getContext('2d');
img.canvas.width = 1000;
img.canvas.height = 1000;
log += 'created big canvas in ' + (Date.now() - t1) + 'ms, ';
// draw image to all 300 canvases
t1 = Date.now();
for (i = 0; i < can.length; i++) {
  can[i].context.drawImage(img.canvas, 0, 0);
}
console.log('drawImage in ', Date.now() - t1);
log += 'drawImage in ' + (Date.now() - t1) + 'ms, ';
log += window.navigator.userAgent + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML = log;
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Comment: If you think this is a bug with Chrome, might make sense filing a bug report, not sure how SO can help with the speed of Chrome versions been slower.

Comment: I filed a bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1480247

Comment: FYI:  I'm on Linux Chrome -> Version 115.0.5790.102  results are `created 300 canvases in 3ms, created big canvas in 0ms, drawImage in 14ms,`   So it could just be 116, based on these numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in chrome/chromium version 117